# How would I be able to set one vertices the same y axis as another one?

Tags: modeling

I'm new to use blender and the current version I'm using in 2.8 and I want to get used to learning this software.

Answer (score 3):

I assume "setting a vertex to the same y axis as another vertex" means that they both should be on the same line perpendicular to Y axis.

## Snapping

You can use snapping for that. You can constrain to the other two axis by pressing shift+x,y or z so that transform operations are constrained to a plane and then hold <kbd>ctrl</kbd> while in transform operation to temporarily enable snapping. Your snapping settings need to be set to Vertex mode:

[image]

## Scaling

You can also use scaling to 0 while using active element as transform pivot and constraining to the XZ axis plane the same way as with snapping. The active vertex will be the one you select the last.

[image]

Comment: Nice solution and very easy to follow. I knew about snapping and the combination of multiple restrictions sure does the trick. Learning more ways every day. Even for some seemingly simple situations.

Comment: Thanks, I am really glad to hear this is easy to follow, that's exactly what I aim to make it. :)

Comment: It sure is, while i tried to go with a simple way to follow, you made the use of shortcuts easy to follow which sooner or later ends up being the way to go to be efficient anyways. I need to learn how to make those gif animations, as they do show so much information (more then a dozen pictures you would have to scroll through) in a compact way.

Comment: There is this [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com/) tool if you are on Windows.

Comment: Great tool, thanks for pointing me in the right direction, i'm sure that a lot answers can profit from tools like this.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the Blender world, and yes 2.8 is a good start.
So you want to set one vertex of an object to the same y-axis (value).
I'll go by example then:
We need to see the coordinates, so in the Viewport press "n" to open the "Transform" tab.
In vertex edit mode, i selected one vertex and moved it a bit in the y direction to build an example.
The vertex has the y-coordinate of -0.55815m, as marked in the picture below.
[image: starter cube entrance]
In the second picture we have the vertex on the other side selected.
[image: other vertex selected]
This time the y-coordinate is -1m, means we have 2 vertices that have different y coordinates and can correct the cube the following way.
You can click on the value behind the "Y:" and it should look like this.
[image: y value is marked]

The y-value is now marked and you can copy it by "ctrl-c" to then select the other vertex again and override the value like this.

[image: vertex one get new y value]

By clicking on the value, in this case -0.55815m it will be selected and you can "ctrl-v" paste the value you copied from the other vertex. The picture shows the already pasted new value of -1m. After which you press enter and confirm thus the new value.
Now the starter cube looks fine again.
[image: starter cube happy]

While there are a lot shortcuts you can and may want to learn, start with the basics and if you need to set values precise, this is a good start. There are a lot tutorials to get used to Blender, well worth the time to watch and especially with the new 2.8+ version, it's fun, so i hope you enjoy yourself with Blender.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to do this: which one you choose will be the one you can reach most quickly, and which disrupts the settings for everything else you're doing at the time the least.

Typically for me it would be:

- Keyboard <kbd>.</kbd> > set the Pivot point to 'Active Element'
- Select the vertices you want to move, and lastly the one you want to move to, making it active.. and ..
- <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> Scale all the selected vertices to 0 in the Y axis (of whichever orientation you're working in).

or, if you want to move all the vertices *on* to the same axis, rather than flatten them along it:  <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>, scaling in all axes *except* Y.

Answer (score -1):

In edit mode select the vertex you want to move, hit 'G', and then hit 'Y' to lock the movement to the Y axis, then just match it, you can press num 1 to align your viewport properly so you will see the y axis in a more precise manner, and you can also hold shift to move it with less speed.